# How much goods can I bring into South Africa without paying import duty?

Tags: south-africa, import-taxes, gifts

I have a watch that was bought through Amazon by a friend who is in South Africa and was sent to me as Amazon does not ship to South Africa. the intention is that i bring the watch with me in my hand luggage to South Africa when i visit. the watch is valued at 137.32 US Dollars (about R1700) and does not contain any precious metals.

Will there be any import duties or any other foreseeable customs issues?

Comment: According to http://www.saembassy.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Travellers-Guide.pdf the duty-free threshold is R 5000, in which case you're fine, but http://www.southafrica-newyork.net/consulate/customs%20and%20excise.html says it's R 1250.

Comment: would i have to declare the time if it is duty free??

Comment: @Annali Typically (and I don't have experience with South Africa), declaring something that is below the allowance is not necessary but, unless you actually trying to smuggle something, there is no downside in approaching customs yourself.

Comment: I can confirm what @Relaxed said from experience: I had something I was unsure about; I simply declared it to a customs officer, and they just waved me on.

Answer (score 5):

South Africa now has a [traveler card](http://www.sars.gov.za/AllDocs/OpsDocs/SARSForms/TC01%20-%20Traveller%20%20Card%20-%20External%20Form.pdf) (14+ MB download) which has to be filled out on arrival. They state that you should declare all goods. This is from the SA government page [here](http://www.sars.gov.za/ClientSegments/Customs-Excise/Travellers/Pages/Arrival-in-SA.aspx). More info [here](http://www.sars.gov.za/AllDocs/OpsDocs/Guides/Customs-G001%20-%20Travellers%20Guide%20-%20External%20Guide.pdf).

The relevant section is here:

[image]

I don't see a section to enter goods value or description, but if asked you should, of course, answer truthfully.